# getUserMedia() in outlook add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I am working on an outlook add-in and wondering if webRTC getUserMedia APIs are available in the desktop app. My add-in worked in outlook web but didn't in desktop app. Further investigating it, it seems like mediaDevices object is not available in the native app.

Is there an alternative or support planned for future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because Office on Windows (including Outlook) currently renders web add-ins in an IE web control, and getUserMedia [isn't available in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Browser_compatibility). This limitation will also impact Outlook Web App users who use IE. For impacted users, consider implementing an alternative or fallback in the add-in if possible.

In future versions, Office on Windows will use either an IE or an Edge control to render web add-ins ([see the slides here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/office-add-ins-community-call-february-13-2019/), starting on slide 11). Which control is used will depend on the Office and Windows version numbers. See the linked slides for the timeline and version numbers.